# Rails routing and before filter question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

lets say i have the following relationship:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
end
```

And I have a route like this:

```
  map.resources :events, :has_many => :tickets
  map.resources :tickets
```

And i have a before filter like this on tickets_controller:

```
 before_filter :get_event

def get_event
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
end
```

And I have an index action on tickets_controller like this:

```
if @event == nil
  @tickets = Ticket.all
else
  @tickets = @event.tickets.all   
end
```

how come if I go to /tickets (where no event instance is passed) it says I still need an event id?

I am trying to keep DRY otherwise i would separate the index action into to actions and exclude one in the before filter.

appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your before_filter is being called

```
@event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
```

and it requires an event_id.

Because of the version of find you are using, that is the version that is looking for a specific id, you are getting a RecordNotFound exception.

You may want to use

```
Event.first(params[:event_id])
```

and check for nil on that.

Comment: that makes sense! appreciate the help Laz!

Answer (score 0):

The other way to handle it is to exclude the filter from the index action:

```
before_filter :get_event, :except => [:index]
```

Then place

```
@events = Event.all
```

into the index action.  Since you will most likely only listing a limited number of events, perhaps:

```
@events.Event.all(:limit => 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to check for the presence of the event_id.

```
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id]) if params[:event_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

the way I would do it is

```
begin
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # do nothing -- can be written to do redirects but not necessary here
end
```

Also, you can write `if @event == nil` as `if !@event`  (note not `unless @event` since the else makes the unless confusing.